# <p> size depending on text inside of it

Tags: html, size

Is there a way to make the `<p>` size fit exactly around the text inside of it?

I have tried auto, no size or anything like that but it would just go the full width of the parent element.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language.  Please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad `display:inline-block` to `p` tag:

```css
div{
  background:green;
  padding:5px
}
p{
  background:blue;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> abc </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do organize every set of tags inside the `<div>`. And modify the div tag to align or something. A better managing is possible.

To give a particular operation on a single tag,use`style` Eg:- `<p style="font-size: 100%;font-style: italic;">I love Java</p>` - *Inline functions*

Another method is by creating an identity to each tag, and applying separate(using `id`) or similar(using `class`) effects to those tags.

Eg:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #hello{
            font-size: 200%;
            color: red;
        }            
        .intro{
            font-size: 100%;
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="hello">Hello World!</h1>
    <p class="intro">Iam developing a website to enpower the nation's security</p>
    <p class="intro">To make my nation proud</p>
</body>
```

Another method is using seperate .css file and link that file using the

```
 <head>
    <link href="stylesheets/BodyStyle.css" type="text/css" /> 
 </head>
```

and in .css file,the same declarations of `<style></style` are made.